# How do I replace the icon on the title bar on a win 10 form

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am trying to replace the icon of a win form with a larger .png
Whether i try to draw a rectangle or load the image; i am not getting anything in the title bar.
I am using visual studio 2019 on a win 64 bit.
The code below is what i am using.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const uint WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
            {
                IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
                try
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
                    {
                        //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20);
                        //g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect);
                        //g.Flush();
                        g.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Picture1.png"), new Point(0, 0));
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, dc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfDYn.png)

Appreciate any help

Comment: That icon in the title bar is either the application icon or the window's icon. In VS, you can assign both of those at design time.

Comment: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe)

Answer (score 0):

Accordin the [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint):

> Return value:  An application returns zero if it processes this message.

If you have processed `WM_NCPAINT`, you cannot call the default `WndProc`

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
        {
            IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            
            try
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
                {
                    //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20);
                    //g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect);
                    //g.Flush();

                    g.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\head.png"), new Point(0, 0));
                    InvalidateRect(m.HWnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, dc);
            }
        }
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);

    }
```

But you need to draw other things yourself, such as system buttons.
As comments, you could create your custom window with the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe).

Removing the Standard Frame with [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize#remarks):

> Starting with Windows Vista, removing the standard frame by simply
> returning 0 when the wParam is TRUE

```
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (m.Msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
        {
            if(m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero)
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
```

This will remove the standard frame, and disable hitting, resizing and moving. The sample you can use `HitTestNCA` in the doc to enable them.

Finally, try to draw the title icon in `PaintCustomCaption` function.

Or you could try [this Customized Form](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc161f9f-2523-4624-a43b-12eb72648808/change-icon-size-in-form?forum=winforms) sample answer by @Aland Li.